# Is Venus part of a DLC in destiny?

Tags: destiny

This is similar to my previous Destiny question but I’ve done all the moon and earth story missions, scouting missions, and strikes that I can do and I can’t move on to Venus or Mars. Are they part of a DLC or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You gain access to Venus and Mars as you progress through the story

Comment: @Wondercricket So is there something wrong my game? That’s the only thing I can think of that would explain why I can’t progress. I’ve done the story missions on earth and the moon and I’m level 15 (so level restrictions shouldn’t be an issue).

Comment: @@Actual_donut Do you remember the last story mission you did? Following [this](https://www.destinypedia.com/Story#Base_Game) guide, once you complete the "Shrine of Oryx" mission, you gain access to Venus for the "A Stranger's Call" mission

Comment: @Wondercricket I’ve completed Shrine of Oryx twice. Edit: I haven’t completed Chamber of Night if that makes a difference. But I can’t select it on the map.

Comment: It's difficult to say for certain without seeing your maps, but I would suggest making sure you've completed all of the story missions on both earth and the moon

Comment: @Wondercricket I’m my other Destiny question I added a picture of my map of the moon but not earth. So that may help.

Answer (score 1):

No, Venus is not part of a DLC in Destiny.

In order to access the first mission on Venus (A Stranger's Call), you need to have completed the requisite story missions on the Moon, as well as meeting a level requirement (I believe it's 12 or 13).

The only destinations that are locked behind DLC are the Reef (House of Wolves), the Dreadnaught (The Taken King) and the Plaguelands (Rise of Iron).